# Using regular expression when scraping with rvest

Tags: r, string, rvest

I'm trying to scrape some parliamentary speeches with `rvest`. The links I have identify a parliamentary session, but I need to scrape the text of individual MPs' speeches.
I am using the general html class '.intervento' because it is consistent across different urls. With that I get a vector of characters with several speeches. However, I am interested in the elements that start with the characters contained in another dataframe column (name_surname). In some cases, multiple elements match the name_surname column and I would like to keep them all.

This is the MWE with the code I have been unsuccessfully using.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

df <- structure(list(name_surname = c("FERDINANDO ADORNATO", "FERDINANDO ADORNATO", 
                                      "LUCIANO AGOSTINI"), text = c("http://documenti.camera.it/apps/commonServices/getDocumento.ashx?idlegislatura=16&sezione=assemblea&tipoDoc=stenografico&idSeduta=0019&nomefile=stenografico&ancora=sed0019.stenografico.tit00030.sub00060.int00020#sed0019.stenografico.tit00030.sub00060.int00020", 
                                                                    "http://documenti.camera.it/apps/commonServices/getDocumento.ashx?idlegislatura=16&sezione=assemblea&tipoDoc=stenografico&idSeduta=0019&nomefile=stenografico&ancora=sed0019.stenografico.tit00030.sub00060.int00120#sed0019.stenografico.tit00030.sub00060.int00120", 
                                                                    "http://documenti.camera.it/apps/commonServices/getDocumento.ashx?idlegislatura=16&sezione=assemblea&tipoDoc=stenografico&idSeduta=0041&nomefile=stenografico&ancora=sed0041.stenografico.tit00020.sub00010.int01320#sed0041.stenografico.tit00020.sub00010.int01320"
                                      )), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

df$text_html <- lapply(df$text, read_html)

# Code that returns all speeches
df$text_final <- lapply(df$text_html, function(x) {
  interventi <- html_nodes(x, '.intervento') %>% html_text(trim = TRUE)
})

# Attempt to select individual speeches
df$text_final2 <- lapply(df$text_html, function(x) {
  x <- html_nodes(x, '.intervento') %>% html_text(trim = TRUE)
  str_subset(x, paste0("^", df$name_surname))
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str_subset` expects a single value, but you are passing it a vector of three names on each of the passes of `lapply` (i.e. the entire column `df$surname`). I would use `map2` to iterate through both columns row by row

```
df$text_final2 <- purrr::map2(df$text_html, df$name_surname, function(text, speaker) {
  x <- html_nodes(text, '.intervento') %>% html_text(trim = TRUE)
  str_subset(x, paste0("^", speaker))
})
```

Alternatively, you could use a rowwise mutate

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(
    text_final3 = text_html |> 
      html_nodes('.intervento') |>  
      html_text(trim = TRUE) |> 
      str_subset(paste0("^", name_surname)) |> 
      list()
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?
It will return a list with the text that follows each name. In the code below `mp`, stands for member of parliament.

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(rvest)
})

fun <- function(x) {
  mp <- x[1]
  link <- x[2]
  page <- read_html(link)
  page %>%
    html_elements('.intervento') %>% 
    html_text(trim = TRUE) %>%
    `[`(grep(mp, .))
  
}

apply(df, 1, fun)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I get this error: Error in UseMethod("read_xml") : no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "list". I am not sure I got your answer, but I want to keep only the elements that start with the MP name.

Comment: @Jasper Have you called the function as I did, with `apply`? (Not `lapply`).